# Return minutes from time to now

Tags: php, time

I'm stuck at something maybe easy but I cannot find an solution of it. 
I try to count how many minutes have past since the time() integer is saved. Now my function looks like:

```
if ($time < $time + 60 * 60 ) {
    return ' not Older than 1 hour';
}
```

And I want something like:

```
if ($time < $time + 60 * 60 ) {
    return '21 minutes old';
}
```

Comment: this will help you to solve your problem . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265942/php-get-time-difference-in-minutes

Comment: Oh didn't know I could do it via DateTime() .. +1 for solid solution :)

Comment: ya you can just by retrieving only current time unless of using date and time i just show you way that how you can  brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(time() - $time < 3600) {
    return 'not older than 1 hour';
}


return ((time() - $time) * 60)." minutes old";
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(time() - 3600 > $time){
    echo date('i', time() - $time) . ' Minutes old';
}
```

see the [date](http://php.net/date) function

Comment: And if I want to check if the time is MORE than one hour?

Comment: just change the "equantion" in the if condition according to your needs